# timeout to client and no entry in logs of IIS 6.0

Tags: iis, http

We are getting and error, where the user clicks on a button and receives a message stating timeout after some time. 
On checking the IIS logs or eventviewer we do not find an entry for the same.
Thus it is not possible to arrive at the cause of issue, as to why the request is not reaching the IIS server.

In case if it could be a network issue, please help to diagnose the problem by providing pointer to a tool to monitor etc

Answer (score 1):

I would start troubleshooting the issue using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler2/version.asp). This should show me where the request is waiting.. Also, I would check HTTPErr logfile located at `C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR` and check for HTTP.sys status of the request.

Let me know if you need assistance looking at the Fiddler or HTTPErr logs.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with running something like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) or [Network Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=983b941d-06cb-4658-b7f6-3088333d062f&displaylang=en) on the client and looking at the HTTP traffic to see what is going on.